# What is better, curl or wget?

Tags: linux, curl, wget

Are they the same or not? Can certain things be done with one but not the other? What are those? Or is it, at the end of the day, a matter of familiarity?

Comment: MarcusQ had an answer suggesting to look at  a comparison done by the curl guy: https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html .  Unfortunately said answer was deleted instead of being turned into a comment.

Comment: If you are looking to send lots of requests by spawning many processes, Wget faster than Curl 2+ times (7s vs 15s on 500 requests nodejs)

Comment: "There's a 'wget' in BusyBox, there's no curl there (it is not the actual wget, just a stripped down clone with the same name)." Thus Alpine has wget out of the box, so I tend to prefer that.

Answer (score 49):

If you are programming, you should use curl. It has a nice api and is available for most languages. Shelling out to the os to run wget is a kludge and shouldn't be done if you have an API interface!

Comment: I have never faced any problem shelling out WGET to Perl scripts to automate downloading stuff. However, with CURL, I frequently encounter **error 18 - transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining** (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759956/curl-error-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining). This error I mostly get while trying to use it in Perl scripts, but WGET never gives me such issues. Shouldn't this be taken into consideration?

Comment: If you are using perl you really should be using the LWP library (LWP::Simple). It is always easier to read response codes, assign functional callbacks, and catch exceptions than to parse the text output of another process.

Answer (score 33):

There is some overlap in functionality. While [GNU wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is a package for retrieving files using HTTP/FTP, [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) transfers data with single URL. As noted in the link shared by [MarkusQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62970/markusq), wget can download recursively - see [this comparison article](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html) for more details by the curl author.

Answer (score 24):

`cURL` is intended for data transfer in both directions while `wget` is for non-interactive downloading file(s) from a particular source. There are [some](/q/9409214) overlaps in functionality, but they are [not meant](/q/6371719) to do exactly [the same things](/q/12846933).

It really depends on what you are trying to do; for simpler tasks like downloading files `wget` and `cURL` are comparable, but this really only scratches the surface of either tool.

Answer (score 18):

They both offer endless options, most of which I've never used. However, I tend to like wget more as it by default saves the output from the URL you give — perfect for downloading. Curl goes the other way, and displays the output directly to the terminal (by default).