# Website gets downloaded partially

Tags: php, apache

I've been having issues with certain pages in the backend of my website. It happens in multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari). The website uses Zend Framework 1.11 and runs on a shared hosting environment (PHP, Apache)

When I try to load certain pages, Chrome simply outputs a blank page. It does download HTML, but sometimes only partially. When I check my web inspector, I see the following (see screenshot). Also, when I try to download the page through Chrome, I get the following error: "curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining". (and indeed, only part of the HTML was downloaded)

Screenshots:

1. http://cl.ly/image/2K371a1p3Y3S
2. http://cl.ly/image/442d2r1y2u2O
3. http://cl.ly/image/3a1M060X182d
4. http://cl.ly/image/0q1p17143F07
5. http://cl.ly/image/2N2p3k0g3F1m
6. http://cl.ly/image/2X371V1t093O

I've also noticed that the failing requests don't show up in Apache's access/error logs.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Martijn

Comment: Have you turned on error_reporting?

Comment: It's seems that apache breaks connection just after he starts transfer page, please provide access and error log for apache.

Comment: @dark_gf, just checked the access/error logs. The requests that I was talking about in my post don't occurs occur in the access/error log.

Comment: Checked this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759956/curl-error-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining) already?

Answer (score 0):

Could this not be caused by a while loop that never ends?