# When curl transfer large data the curl module, error "transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining"

Tags: php, curl, php-5.4

Currently I have an issue to prepare fix it.

The error:

```
transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

context : php 5.4

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759956/curl-error-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining

Comment: thanks one more time see those answer.