# Guzzle Pool: how to wait for all requests to finish without timing out?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I was using Guzzle Pool to request data (around 1-2 MB with each request) from an external server for the past 6 months. I'm doing 5 simultaneous requests at once. However, things have changed and the external server seems to be overloaded and therefore became very slow. Sometimes it's very fast like 1-2 seconds, but many times the server needs to wait 2+ minutes for each request.

This shouldn't be an issue though. However nowadays (since it becomes slow to make requests), some of my requests in the pool are returning an error:

`cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

It usually does that after waiting for exactly 2 minutes.

The interesting thing though is that if I make the request through Postman (for example) then, I still have to wait 2-3+ minutes, but I got the response in the end.

So this led me to believe that Guzzle's blocking the requests after 2 minutes. I, however, couldn't find any settings to change this. I have even tried sending a `Keep Alive` and a `Content-Length` header, but they did not work (maybe I didn't use them correctly though).

Here is a part of my current code that's doing the Guzzle Pool requests. (I'm using PHP 7.1, Guzzle 6.3 and Laravel 5.7).

```
$headers = ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token];

$client  = new Client();

$requests = function ($urls, $headers)
{
    foreach ($urls as $key => $url)
    {
        yield new Requests('GET', $url, $headers);
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests($urls, $headers),
[
    'concurrency' => 5,
    'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index)
    {
        echo 'fulfilled -> ' . $index;
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index)
    {
        echo 'rejected -> ' . $index . ' -> error:' . $reason->getMessage();
    },
]);

$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();
```

Unfortunately,  I cannot share the external server URL, because it's private.

What am I doing wrong here, that doesn't allow the request to wait for it to finish / send over the data?

---

**Update:** I have tried @Alexey Shokov's recommendation, which got rid of the rejected states. The requests are not timing out at 2 minutes now. However I get null as a response once I get something back from those previously `timed out` sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue on the server side. The error indicated that cURL client sees a mismatch between expected response size and the real response size, sent by the server.

Take a look at [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848947/322079), same issue. I think it worths trying to set HTTP version to 1.0 as stated in the discussion with [Guzzle's `version` option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#version) or directly in the `Request` object (`yield new Requests('GET', $url, $headers, null, '1.0')`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried doing this and I don't get any errors (rejects) anymore however I'm getting 'null' in the response data. Why could it be that it's working pretty good on a software like PostMan, but not working with Guzzle?