# cURL error 18 error coming in laravel sendgrid driver

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

Below error coming in sendgrid driver. this is used to work ... suddenly not started to work

> exception: "GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException"
>   file: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\qhse\QHSE_Backend\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php"
>   line: 186
>   message: "cURL error 18: transfer closed with 116 bytes remaining to read (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

This is the code I'm using to send:

```
return $this
    ->view('email.action')
    ->subject('demo')
    ->from('noreply@admin-int.com')
    ->sendgrid([
        'personalizations' => [
            [
                'substitutions' => [
                    ':myname' => 's-ichikawa',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ])
    ->with(['arr' => $this->data]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. this was due to an invalid API key.

```
cURL error 18: transfer closed with 116 bytes remaining to read (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) {"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException(code: 401): cURL error 18: transfer closed with 116 bytes remaining to read (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at /var/www/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:201)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to simply `composer update` and the issue went away.

An alternative, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759956/curl-error-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining/1761718#1761718), is to use http 1.0 instead of http 1.1. In this case, that can be done by editing `s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver/src/Transport/SendgridTransport.php:post()` (assuming you also use this package) to say `return $this->client->post($this->endpoint, $payload, ['version' => 1.0]);` instead.

(and then of course, somehow moving that edit out of /vendor/, or forking that repository)